# what assert do in the neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I saw the assert layer between some layers of NN.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256) # Note: None is the batch size
```

what does this assert do? and is this necessary?

https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/generative/dcgan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assertion is exactly for what its name says, Assertion!
in python we use "assert" command to be sure if a statement is exactly equals to what we expect. look at this simple code:

```
a = 2
b = 3
assert a + b == 5
```

This part of code runs without any error because  a + b is exactly what we expect, 5. But if you change the code in this way:

```
assert a + b == 6 # 6 or other any number except 5,It doesn't matter
```

The code will throw an Assertion Error, because a  + b != 6 ...
The assertion command in the code which you mentioned, checks if the output of the model is exactly in shape of 7 * 7 * 256, otherwise it throws an error.
 This is useful to prevent the probable problems in next lines of code because of dimension mismatch, so if you remove it, nothing will happen but you will not be noticed if the dimension is not what you expect.